# How to upgrade a smart contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, design

I'm building a smart contract that is sort of an index of signed documents (pointing to ipfs for the actual docs).

What if I want to add some functionality to my `app` down the road and need to upgrade the contract?

I understand I need to make a new contract, but how about transferring the current state of the old contract to the new?

Would it cost a lot of XTZ to initialize a new contract with a big state? Is there another approach for achieving this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because values of type `lambda` can be kept in storage or passed as parameters (either as `lambda` or as `bytes` to be `UNPACK`ed), it is *possible* to write contracts which can upgrade themselves... This won't always make sense, but might sometimes be useful.

For example, one of the very early mainnet contracts appears to have a kind of upgrade mechanism: https://tzscan.io/KT1R3uoZ6W1ZxEwzqtv75Ro7DhVY6UAcxuK2. The configured owner can supply a lambda to one of the entry points, which will be placed in storage and will override the contract's behavior in some cases.

Answer (score 10):

> Disclaimer: This is just an example for educational purposes, don't use it in production.

Here is a fairly primitive upgradable design for a Liquidity smart contract:

[image: Amendable smart contract]

**Proxy Contract**

- Holds the state / storage
- Points to a Logic Contract, and proxies its entry points
- Can be amended / upgraded, by its rightful owner. You can run into decentralization / governance issues here - all the underlying logic contract changes are still tracked on-chain, so it's a trade-off.
- Exposes an entry point `setData`, consumed by the Logic Contract to apply storage changes

**Logic Contract**

- Is called exclusively by the Proxy Contract
- Each entry point call, results into a `setData` entry point call on the Proxy Contract

In theory, you should be able to implement this using Liquidity's ['module-like contract system'](http://www.liquidity-lang.org/doc/reference/liquidity.html#the-module-like-contract-system). For the above described to work well, you must carefully implement a decent ACL (who can call which entry points).

Answer (score 2):

Cryptonomic [published an article](https://medium.com/the-cryptonomic-aperiodical/building-up-blockchains-tezos-proxy-contract-616b55dfdca8) on exactly this topic recently.